# MySQL ERROR 1064 (42000) ... IDENTEFIED BY

Tags: mysql

Люди добрые, отакая от фигня. Что это может быть, подскажите пожалуйста.

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON students_db.* TO 'students_db_user'@'localhost' IDENTEFIED BY 'password';

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTEFIED BY 'password'' at line 1

Comment: IDENTIFIED же..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример как нужно содавать пользователя и давать ему права, можете по примеру построить свой

```
CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```